# Internet Explorer Can't Adjust Inline List Item Width?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, html-lists

I have an unordered list whose list items are displaying inline. However, its layout is rather complicated, so let me show you the Fiddle:

- Fullscreen: http://jsfiddle.net/spryno724/F5CFD/embedded/result/
- Code: http://jsfiddle.net/spryno724/F5CFD/

Notice how the unordered list items stretch to the height of the tallest list item, using the `display: table-cell` property (except for the first list item). This allows the first list item to have a vertical line extend the entire height of the unordered list, with the letter "A" vertically aligned to the top.

This presentation works excellent in most browsers, with the notable exception of Internet Explorer 8<sup>[1]</sup>, of course. Here are some screenshots, in case you don't have IE8:

- Excellent rendering in Chrome: https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/oI6rWHT8iS_0nKVQRb1o_hV2JJooBc4dMF1MOKsl3b4?feat=directlink
- IE8 rendering the same page, with the IE developer tools highlighting the erratic width of the third list item: https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/_n-WvfHYgUrPJ6jTdk24KxV2JJooBc4dMF1MOKsl3b4?feat=directlink

Any ideas what I can do to keep the same look as you see in Chrome (or any other browser other than IE1-IE8)?

Thank you for your time.

[1]  What have we ever done to you IE8 that you hate us so???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, IE doesn't render the table-cell property, so you have to resort to various hacks. Fortunately, this one works pretty well.

```
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    *display:inline;
    zoom: 1;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 130px;
    min-width: 130px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 15px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

This will allow the elements to align in an inline-block fashion in IE, giving you cross-browser inline elements.

Comment: Thank you, I tried your suggestion, and it basically displayed them vertically, just like an ordinary unordered list.

Comment: Oops, forgot to add the display for everything but IE.Try that.

Comment: By applying your styles it look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/F5CFD/2/ Try it in IE

Comment: @Torr3nt Really close! Can the first list item stretch to the full height?

Comment: Now adding: `display: inline-block` and `*display:inline` it looks fine. but the border of `section` having text `A` is not increasing. In this case spryno724 needs to use a fixed height for it.

Comment: I don't know of a cross-browser compatible way to do that without using JS. Great plugin called equalHeights will do it for you though. http://www.cssnewbie.com/example/equal-heights/plugin.html. Maybe I'm wrong, but that's all that I know of haha.

Comment: @spryno724 Use CSS as suggested by Torr3nt, but fix you min-height for `.section` as seen in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/F5CFD/17/

Comment: @Torr3nt That's fantastic! Thank you, Torr3nt! You got my wheels spinning in the right direction. I was able to build on your idea, and by using absolute positioning (which I really don't like using) I was able to get it working cross-browser: http://jsfiddle.net/F5CFD/18/

Comment: Fantastic Ahsan! Thank you for your input, too!

Comment: Actually, revision 17 only works with lists that are 225px tall. Revision 18 will scale to a list of any height. Thank you, though!

Comment: Be sure to keep your IE hack at *display:inline; 

Inline-table decided to break everything in IE